# Toggling between rows of a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to angular js(1.5).
I have a dynamically generated table.I have to append a down arrow for each row in the first column and based on the arrow selected the data corresponding to the selected row should be displayed in the div.
I am able to toggle i.e. click of arrow will open div and another click will close it. But upon click of arrow of first row arrow the details for all the rows are being fetched.Kindly Help.

I have tried linking the index of selected row to fetch the details.

html file

```
<div>application
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" data-toggle="collapse" ng-class="{'selected': $index == selectedRow}"
        ng-click="showAppDetails($index)"></span>
</div>

<div ng-if="selectedRow == index" ng-hide="!IsHidden">
    <p> hellop</p>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
 $scope.IsHidden = false;
 $scope.selectedRow = null;
 $scope.showAppDetails= function(index){
     $scope.selectedRow = index;
      $scope.IsHidden = $scope.IsHidden ? false : true;
```

Comment: were you trying to use `$index` or do you have `$scope.index` assigned somewhere?

Comment: $scope.selectedRow = index; is there any other assignment required/?

Comment: Can you give us more code please? i.e the while repeat code

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div ng-if="selectedRow == $index" ng-hide ="!IsHidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="detail in appDetails track by $index">
<div class="icon" ng-click="selectedDetail=detail"></div>
</tr>
<div ng-if="selectedDetail != null">
  <p>{{selectedDetail}}</p>
</div>
</table>


selectedDetail=null;
```

This may help.